# Print intermediate result Sum function

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I write simple code in Wolfram Mathematica:

```
x = 2
k = 0
n = 15
total = Sum[((-1^k)*(x^(4*k + 1))) / (((2*k)!) * (4*k + 1)), k, n]
```

I want print result (the sum all members) and print all(!!!) intermediate results function `Sum`. How this make?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
x=2;k=0;n=15;
Table[((-1^k)*(x^(4*k+1)))/(((2*k)!)*(4*k+1)),{k,n}]
```

That gives you a list of 15 elements.

Notice that I changed k,n to {k,n}.

Then `Total[%]` will add those to create a sum.

Comment: Sorry, I see something simular on stack trace, but not intermideate values :)

Comment: Perhaps I didn’t put it that way ... I meant each term of the sum, that is, in the case n = 15, then 15 elements of the sum

Comment: Thanks! This function, which I searched!

Answer (score 1):

Your syntax is calculating a multiple *indefinite* sum, e.g.

```
Sum[Defer[g + h], g, h]
```

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indefinite_sum

If you add brackets around `k, n` you will obtain the sum Bill's answer shows.

```
total = Sum[((-1^k)*(x^(4*k + 1)))/(((2*k)!)*(4*k + 1)), {k, n}]
```